# Paypal API Support for Trading platform usecase

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

### Use-case

1. A Trading-platform for selling goods where each subscriber can purchase and sell ( eg. eBay )
2. Trading-platform takes commission for each transaction

### Flow of actions

1. Buyer execute a purchase
2. Funds are transferred from the buyer account to the Trading-platform account
3. **PayPal takes it's transaction commission**
4. Trading-platform takes it's commission
5. Trading-platform transfer the reminding funds from it's account to the Seller account
6. **PayPal takes it's transaction commission**

### Problem at hand

1. As can be seen in the above 'Flow of actions' PayPal will charge for commission twice
2. this composite transaction model considerably complicates implementation/cost.

### Feedback required

- Is there any payment model with which this can be avoided?
- Is there any payment model where for each transaction a subset of the total sum is sent to the trading platform account ?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments) for this.  With Adaptive Payments, you can split payments up and set who pays what fees.